# Rails pull out and sort data with join

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I want to pull out and sort all `Process` by `company_name`. To get company_name for one process I need to do something like this:

```
  company_name = Process.first.inquiry_field_responses
                  .joins(:inquiry_field)
                  .where(inquiry_fields: { name: 'company_name' })

  company_name.first&.value
```

How to pull out and order those processes by company_name?

Answer (score 1):

You can sort ascending as below,

```
  company_name = Process.first.inquiry_field_responses
                  .joins(:inquiry_field)
                  .where(inquiry_fields: { name: 'company_name' })
                  .order("inquiry_fields.name")
```

To sort desceding, use `order("inquiry_fields.name desc")`

Comment: To pull out `company_name` I need to do either - `company_name.first&.value` where company_name is equal this whole join.